# Can not get authorization code from login box.com

Tags: oauth, box-api

I try get auth token by instruction: http://developers.box.com/oauth/
Send GET request: https://api.box.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&state=authenticated&redirect_uri=MYURL.
Input login/password and click allow, but do not get any authorization code. Instead of this open simply box.com page.

If I click deny, then ok, I see opened url with error access_denied.
I'm trying this actions from browser.

Why I do not get code after login?

Comment: This has started happening for me as well.  It was working properly earlier in the day yesterday.

Comment: John Hoerr, but what changed on your side?

Comment: Nothing, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you redirecting to an HTTPS URI?

Comment: seanrose, you are best :) Worked with https. The only pity, that I do not know what need todo for non-web applications. For android, example. From box doc not clear, what we can used in this case for response_type/redirect_uri

Comment: We also support custom URL schemes e.g. something like spotify://someaddress. This is what iOS does, is it the same in Android? Apologies if this isn't clear in the doc, we're working on it. (here is what iOS does http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

Comment: seanrose, redirect_uri not problem, because we can use any https url, anyway we get redirect url with code value.

Comment: But I get next error. I try get access token by article "Getting the Access Token". Set all params. Try 2 different ways:
1) POST request with "short" url: https://api.box.com/oauth2/token with multipart entity params;
2) POST request: http://pastebin.com/026RH8ZE. Client id/secret I get from "Edit a Box Application" -> "OAuth2 parameters".

Comment: In both case I get "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}".
I try send request without "grant_type" param, get error http page:
"Page Error. The page you were viewing has expired. Please go back and try your request again."

Comment: My mistake. All worked ok (case 1).
But interested another: dates in request used ISO 8601.
But see in json value "2012-12-12T11:15:04-08:00". What is last ":"? I think, correct value is "2012-12-12T11:15:04-0800", no?

Comment: Another issue. Try upload file by [doc](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file).
Get error: `{"type":"error","status":404,"code":"not_found","help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":{"folder_id":null},"request_id":"...."}`.  
Change param "**parent_id**" on "**folder_id**", starts worked correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by creating a separate page where the user can login with box, though I doubt that's the best way for you to address the issue. Advice from Sean Rose obviously is your best bet. Here's what I did to get the code:

The user visits [https] mysite.com/login_with_box to authorize access. After the user clicks on "Allow," she redirects to [https] mysite.com/redirect_uri, the url of which obviously matches what you've provided as your app's redirect_uri. After the redirect, the user should see the code in [https] mysite.com/redirect_uri?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I had to go with [https] instead of https:// because I'm a new user here.